# changing the url into dash instead of underscore using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url

Hi im using codeigniter framework because its really cool when it comes to MVC thing. I have a question regarding in the url thing. Usually when saving a controller, lets say in the about us page it has to do something like this About_us extends CI_Controller. When that comes to the url thing it goes like this test.com/about_us. I want that my url is not underscore. I want to be dashed something like this test.com/about-us. How will i able to use the dash instead of using underscore???

any help is greatly appreciated
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just have to create routes for your pages, as far as I am aware, there is no config directive to change the separating character, or replace '-' with '_' in CI_Router, (probably wouldn't be too hard to add this).

To allow for '-' instead of '_':

Create a file in application/core/MY_Router.php

Change 'MY_' to whatever value is specified in your config directive: `$config['subclass_prefix']`

insert code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Router extends CI_Router {
  function _set_request($segments = array()) {
    if (isset($segments[0]))
      $segments[0] = str_replace('-','_',$segments[0]);

    if (isset($segments[1])) {
      $segments[1] = str_replace('-','_',$segments[1]);
    }

    return parent::_set_request($segments);
  }
}
```

Comment: do have any samples on it?

Comment: of routes? in application/config/routes.php add $route['about-us'] = 'About_us';

Comment: all of the pages im about to use on that?? one by one?

Comment: @bobcatnyxz Check my Edit.. work around for replacing - with _ for controllers and methods in the URI.

Comment: thanks @RaggaMuffin-420 it works now without adding one by one in the config/routes.php

Comment: You shouldn't replace any code within the `system` directory, it could have some serious implications. Better practice would be to [extend the Router class.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)

Comment: @Lefters You shouldn't be such a scaredy cat.  replacing a - with an _ at this point won't have any implictions as its right before the validation method, where there shouldn't be ANY - in the strings anyway.  Thanks for your feedback though and don't forget to upvote

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 this is not correct way to that you cannot modify the CORE SYSTEM file. if you change the codeigniter version I means system folder then it will not work. Extend the core file. it is better way.

Comment: @SKG why does it work then?! sure there is a massively long winded way around by extending it and overriding the method etc... but whats the point? the CI version is not hard coded into the core, its an OPEN SOURCE project, its not like its some mythical creature, CI is very simple in how it works...

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 I didn't told you that it will not work. It would work perfectly. What I told you is that it is not correct way to do.  user Lefters also mentation about that. And please google about it you will get proper answer

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 No worries :) _Working_ != _Best practice_ I am pragmatic, but I don't think it's massively long winded to extend the class - it's trivial. There are numerous benefits to extending rather than tinkering with the core. If you want to update the version of CI, you replace the system folder with the new version, this would overwrite your change; not an issue with extending the class. It would likely be easier to maintain too, it would be more apparent how the behaviour had been altered, rather than having to root around in the system folder.

Comment: @Lefters So post your trivial answer then.

Comment: pfft, who down-voted?  I have changed the answer completely. Better send out a telegram to the user to make sure he has complied with the strict codeigniter ethics.

Comment: Because I was being shouted at by people for editing System files.. this is technically the 'Right way' to do it!!

Answer (score 2):

Code Ignitor 3 has this built-in option. In your routes.php:

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Just change this to "TRUE" and you can use either `_` or `-` in URL

[Here is a detailed article how to fix it](http://promofex.com/post/replace-uri-dashes-with-underscores-in-codeigniter).